# SSIS expression fails to validate

Tags: ssis

I have set a following expression in SSIS derived column component:

```
TRIM(xCOL) == "" ? (DT_STR,7,1252)xCOL : NULL(DT_STR,7,1252)
```

However, this fails to validate - I get the following error:

> Error at PKG: For operands of the conditional operator, the data type
>   DT_STR is supported  only for input columns and cast operations. The
>   expression "TRIM(xCOL) == "" ?  (DT_STR,7,1252)xCOL :
>   NULL(DT_STR,7,1252)" has a DT_STR operand that is not an input  column
>   or the result of a cast, and cannot be used with the conditional
>   operation. To perform  this operation, the operand needs to be
>   explicitly cast with a cast operator.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unicode - the bane of all SSIS things that you would think just work.

> TRIM(xCOL) == "" ? (DT_STR,7,1252)xCOL :   NULL(DT_WSTR, 7)

By default, expressions on strings have a return type of Unicode (DT_WSTR). You can prove this yourself by replacing your last expression with an empty string `""`. Look at at the type that the derived column is assigned as - it's a DT_WSTR

```
TRIM(xCOL) == "" ? (DT_STR,7,1252)xCOL :  ""
```

The resolution then is to cast the result of the *entire* expression to your desired type. (I also think you have a logic issue since I'm assuming you are inspecting the trimmed string to determine if it's empty/zero length and then casting it to NULL). Also note, that if you ever do get a NULL in for your xCOL field, this will blow up.

```
(DT_STR, 7, 1252)((TRIM(xCOL) == "") ? NULL(DT_WSTR, 7) :  TRIM(xCOL))
```

## Source data

```
SELECT 'Hello' AS xCOL
UNION ALL SELECT ''
```

## Results

[image]

Comment: This is just insane... I wonder if MS will do something to make those expressions more user-friendly because such a simple expression should not have these kinds of pitfalls.

Comment: The bane of all things SSIS is right! why not default to non-Unicode

Answer (score 6):

Like the error says, you must explicitly cast with a cast operator.

```
TRIM(xCOL) == "" ? (DT_STR,7,1252)xCOL : (DT_STR,7,1252)NULL(DT_STR,7,1252)
```

Comment: And how ridiculous is this syntax, Microsoft ?`(DT_STR,7,1252)NULL(DT_STR,7,1252)`

Comment: SSIS syntax has always been ... silly? But then you look at Informatica, and you hug your MS pillow a little tighter ...

Comment: Well, since i have not seen Informatica then perhaps i need to count my blessings!

Comment: Unbelievable. I was pulling my hair out. This was to correct answer for my scenario:

LEN(column_name) == 0 ? (DT_STR,10,1252)NULL(DT_STR,10,1252) : column_name